# Using Variable Inside $_POST[ ]

Tags: php

How to use variable inside $_POST as i have used the following code but it says undefined offset in second line. How can i solve it?

```
    $p = $_GET['cii'];
$selectOption = $_POST[$p];
```

Below is the code:

```
echo'<form method ="POST">
            <select name="'.$abc[3].'">
                <option value="slow">slow</option>
                <option value="medium">medium</option>
                <option value="fast">fast</option>
                </select>
                <br>
                <a href ="?change&&cii='.$abc[3].'">Click to change</a>
            </form>';
```

$abc[] has some numbers and the select box is made with same name as the number.

Comment: what does echo $p prints?

Comment: It will print number which is taken from url-@reza

Comment: then check if $_post have the value of same variable. try var_dump($_POST), see if that index exits or not

Comment: its printing NULL-@reza

Comment: then you are not sending any value with post method.... show us your html form where you are setting the values

Comment: problem is here. no value is posted by clicking a link. post value set when you submit the forms (by submit button or by js)

Answer (score 1):

Almost there:

```
    $p = 'cii';
    $selectOption = $_POST[$p];
```

Answer (score 0):

you are accessing same page when you come first time you get `undefined offset`

So first check existence

```
 if(isset($_GET['cii'])){
   $p = $_GET['cii'];
   $selectOption = $_POST[$p];
 }
```

Also no need to add double `&&` just use single `&` here

```
<a href ="?change&cii='.$abc[3].'">Click to change</a>
```

Assuming variable `$abc[3]` gives you right value.